# HTML special character issue on server only , on local it's fine

Tags: php, html, apache, character-encoding

My `<meta charset="utf-8">`

and I'm having special charcter problem html content on web server (production) only on my local server ([Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)) it's fine

For example this `India’s` looks fine on local but on server it looks like this `Indiaâ€™s`

And I have lots of html content for a big site. If I would go to fix every charcter manually it will take time and Also i don't see this problem on local so everytime I need to fix and upload to server to chek the issue has been solved or not

**my questions**

- How can i make it possible to my local server to show html with
  charcter problem `Indiaâ€™s`
- Is there a way to solve this problem automatically?

Comment: You get `â€™` if you display utf-8 encoded `’` as ISO 8859-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could also be a problem of the default-charset configuration of your web server. If you use apache put

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

in a .htaccess file in your root directory.

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/setting-charset-in-htaccess.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode your page to UTF-8 format when saving your file (not just add to meta)

Comment: Thanks for reply. How to do that? I use Sublime text 2

Comment: To be honest I'm not going to Google how to do that with your specific editor... I think your capable. :-)